# Structure of 'be safe[adjective] of something'

Tags: word-meaning

The following paragraph is from the novel the Moon and Sixpence.

> Dr. Weitbrecht-Rotholz belongs to that school of historians which believes that human nature is not only about as bad as it can be, but a great deal worse; and *certainly the reader is safer **of** entertainment in their hands* than in those of the writers who take a malicious pleasure in representing the great figures of romance as patterns of the domestic virtues.

I understand the italic part as the reader who reads the book of that kind of historians would feel more comfortable. But I don't get the **of**. There is no *safe of* in my English dictionaries and if it is binded to *entertainment*, a noun seems to be positioned in front of *of*.

What is that *of*?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me. Looks like an error. Could it be a typo?

Comment: Old fashioned way of saying 'more likely to get entertainment from them'. Maugham was writing in 1919.

Comment: What @MichaelHarvey said. But that superlative + preposition use is still relatively acceptable today with the near-synonymous ***surer*** rather than ***safer***, as witness the many written instances of *[The writer [**is surer of success**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+surer+of+success%22) [if he remembers that his primary purpose is to entertain the reader.]*

Comment: ...note that we still use that preposition today with near-synonymous ***...assured of** [some desired goal].*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Michael Harvey's hint in the comments, I had a look in the OED and found this entry:

> **safe, adj. (and int.)**
>
> 7.
>
> a. With of. Sure to obtain. Now rare.
>
> 1538   M. Coverdale tr. M. Luther Expos. Magnificat sig. D.viii   Such a God, as doth not despyse the poore, despysed & vyle, but wyteth them safe of hys owne syghte, that so hys harte be stablyshed in fayth, hope and charite.
>
> ?1614   G. Chapman tr. Homer Odysses iii. 36   Euery Myrmidon..safe of home.
>
> 1667   S. Pepys Diary 23 Aug. (1974) VIII. 398   I find most people pleased with their being at ease and safe of a peace.
>
> 1802   R. Southey La Caba 3   Here I stand, Safe of my purpose now!
>
> 1846   W. M. Thackeray Let. 9 Feb. (MS.)    What I meant by ‘Safe’ is the best word to be applied to a play I think—safe of a real agreeable—of course I don't know how permanent—success.
>
> 1874   For Beauty's Sake ii. 25   He is safe of a warm welcome from me.
>
> 1911   P. H. Brown Hist. Scotl. I. iii. ii. 113   Macduff was not slow to carry his tale where he knew he was safe of a favourable hearing.

Source: "safe, adj. (and int.)". OED Online. March 2022. Oxford University Press. https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/169673?redirectedFrom=safer (accessed June 08, 2022).

Suffice to say it's so rare, I've never come across it before. You learn something new every day!

Comment: A good find! +1. Well done.

Comment: I _knew_ I had seen it in Pepys.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - yeah, thanks to you!!  Anyway, it has a very distinct "old-fashioned" sound to it today. Amazing how language changes.

Comment: When I was 14 my father gave me a book of Maugham's collected short stories, as he knew I liked older stuff. A pleasant style I still think.

Comment: We didn't have 'young adult' books when I was a boy. I had a diet of my uncles' sci-fi mags and paperback novels, plus Dickens, HG Wells, Maugham, DH Lawrence, etc. Plus much stuff you would call rubbish these days.